# How to make Date Fields not be required on an .asp form to successfully submit to an Access DB

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I have a form that has three sets of dates with each set having a start date and an end date field.  My problem is that if the user doesn't fill in all three dates sets, the data does not submit to the database.  A user may not need to fill out all three forms.  Here is my code for the date fields.

```
<br>
<font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp;Payweek Starting: 
<input type="hidden" id="DPC_TODAY_TEXT1" value="today">
<input type="hidden" id="DPC_BUTTON_TITLE" value="Open calendar...">
<input type="hidden" id="DPC_MONTH_NAMES" value="['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']">
<input type="hidden" id="DPC_DAY_NAMES" value="['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']">
</font>
<input type="text" name="w1a" id="DPC_DEFAULT_FORMAT" value="MM/DD/YYYY" />
</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
<br>
<font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp;Payweek Ending: 
<input type="text" name="w1b" id="DPC_DEFAULT_FORMAT0" value="MM/DD/YYYY" />
<font face="Arial" size="2"> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<br>
```

The other two sets of date fields are coded the same as the End Date above.  Any help on how to make the fields not be required to successfully submit to the db is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is all over the place.  The `<html>` and `<head>` tags appear in the middle of your code. You have some basic issues here to be resolved first.

Comment: What are the properties of the date field in your access db. Allow Nulls feature?

Comment: Paul, I edited the code...the tags you are referring to are not in the code for the .asp page. This was a copy error on my part..this is the first time I have copied code into the editor...please forgive the error...Zee Tee, my access table does allow for nulls.  Thans